# Product of the reaction between hexane‐2,5‐dione and ammonium carbonate

Tags: organic-chemistry

> [image: hexane‐2,5‐dione and (NH4)2CO3]
>
> Which of the following statement is INCORRECT?
>
> (A) The product X has a five membered ring.
> (B) The product X is aromatic.
> (C) The degree of unsaturation of the product X is 3.
> (D) The product X has a six membered ring.

Ammonium carbonate will probably lose a proton and one of the carbonyls may be protonated. But from here onwards I can't find any leads. Does the lone pair of other oxygen atom plays a role?

Usually the heat provided may lead to a cyclic structure, but I am not sure.

Comment: Yes it is a cyclic compound. First think, what would happen to ammonium nitrate when it is heated?

Comment: Ammonia gas , carbon dioxide and water is released...nitrogen lone pair will attack on carbonyl carbon and the oxygen will attack the other carbonyl carbon...is this assumption correct? But what happens next?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Heating $\ce{(NH4)2CO3}$ will generate $\ce{NH3 + CO2 + H2O}.$ Out of these, $\ce{NH3}$ will act as a nucleophile as it's the most nucleophilic of the products. Addition of $\ce{NH3}$ to the two ketones, followed by elimination of water molecules (due to the high temperature provided by ∆) will generate the final product as follows:

[image]

The product is a five-membered aromatic ring called 2,5-dimethylpyrrole.

Comment: Try to avoid "lassos" in mechanisms. Use arrows. ;)

Comment: @user55119 Well,my handmade mechanisms tend to have a lot of lassos,still will keep that in mind later :)