# Unable to form the product formed via rearrangement

Tags: organic-chemistry, carbonyl-compounds, amines, rearrangements

[image]

Ok so I first reacted one of the carbonyl groups with NH2OH to form an oxime. And then a Beckmann rearrangement takes place followed by tautomerism. Then the lone pair on nitrogen did an intramolecular attack on the other carbonyl to form a six membered ring.[image: product image] But I am unable to form the correct product which is option (A). Any help on how to proceed and is my approach correct?

Comment: Related: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/124166/product-of-the-reaction-between-hexane-2-5-dione-and-ammonium-carbonate/124171#124171

Comment: Amide nitrogens are not nucleophilic, the oxygen is. No need for the Beckmann.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forget the Beckmann, the oxime is still nucleophilic through N (imagine the N-hydroxy enamine tautomer if that helps). Have it attack the second carbonyl intramolecularly (and hence favoured) to give a dihydropyridine. Dihydropyridines are unstable with respect to aromatisation unless substituted with strongly electron withdrawing groups. The N-hydroxy-dihydropyridine spontaneously will lose H2O to give the pyridine.